# Android: How do I avoid starting activity which is already in stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

Lets try to explain my question:
I got an application and a service.
The application is started with activity A.
The service sends a broadcast that will let the application start Activity B
Now the user starts activity C.

Now the service wants to start activity B again. But how do I let him know that the activity is still on the stack, or is there an intent flag for this?

How do I avoid that it will launch activity B because its already in the stack?

Comment: What is D exactly? Is it code you are writing? If so, the answer is simple, **don't** call `StartActivity(B)`.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote my question :)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I think you need to make your activity B `singleInstance` that if it's already create you don't want to create again, that is [launch mode of the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) can be defined in manifest `android:launchMode` that defines how the activity *will be instanciated*.

in your case use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: But if I set the launchMode to singleInstance I will not get the onActivityResult callbacks rightly.

Comment: Work like a charm!

Answer (score 30):

You can use flag **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**. If the activity is already running it will bring that to front instead of creating new activity.

If you add **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** with this, then all the activities after this activity in the backstack will be cleared.

Comment: This is exaclty what I don't want to happen. If there is already a activity over the started activity. It shouldnt be overridden.

Comment: This will not override the activity. It will bring front the already started activity only.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is not work for me.. this always start new activity .. 
please help me out

Comment: @VaishaliSutariya try FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Starting activity with this intents makes the onCreate method to be called again.

Answer (score 11):

If the activity will be on the top if already started, set the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) flag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is escpecially usefull when using a sidebar/drawer and you don't wanta to open an activity twice when already in front.

Comment: I am starting an activity from a servi using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, the activity does not start and I get this error:

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

Approaches `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and just adding flags to the `Intent` do not work for me.
What works is that:

In the code where activity gets started:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityThatHasToBeStarted.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the `ActivityThatHasToBeStarted`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // Code for this creation
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` instead of `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
[Good article about the differences](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the second activity anymore, it is good practise to finish it, then you should do this on the second activity after the operation is ended:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
finish();
```

Comment: This is good, but returns null on the TextViews of the first page activity.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you use **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** as it will remove all activities which start on top of your targeted activity.

eg :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(sourceActivity, Target activity);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent)
```